# I would like to get one rows if unique columns values are same

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

From this result

```
**Col 1                                 Col2        Col3**
907475DD-BA56-48CD-A2CC-D29B7C86ACF6    154000.00   0.00
907475DD-BA56-48CD-A2CC-D29B7C86ACF6    0.00        15000.00
```

To this result

```
**Col 1                                 Col2        Col3**
907475DD-BA56-48CD-A2CC-D29B7C86ACF6    154000.00   15000.00
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Group by the column you want to be unique and use aggregate functions to get the max of the other columns.

```
select col1, max(col2), max(col3)
from your_table
group by col1
```